# performance differences of using all fields instead "*" in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I know when you don't want all fields of a table it would be better if you use field names instead of "*".

but the question is that what are the differences between selecting all fields of a table with "*" in comparison to writing them all one by one?

PS: database is Postgres 13 and it's in the row store model.

Comment: Why not try it out and see what happens? This might depend on so many factors, like the number of columns and rows in your table, that I would assume there is not a single true answer

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Comment: @NicoHaase , let's suppose 15 fields ( columns) and 5M records.

Comment: So, why not run some benchmarks and check for differences?

Comment: @NicoHaase I will do, meanwhile I wanted to know other people saying about this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, 
I added a 5 000000 records to my table. 
the result of explain for "*" : `Seq Scan on trip  (cost=0.00..15205.00 rows=500000 width=341)`.
Seq Scan on trip  (cost=0.00..15205.00 rows=500000 width=341)

. cost of both are them same, does it means it does not different?

Comment: @NicoHaase beside explain what other benchmark you suggest?

Comment: Why not run the query multiple times to see a difference? That's how you benchmark stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no performance difference whatsoever, it's querying the same data after all.

The difference between writing one or the other in your code is that when you will add more columns to the table in the future, `*` would then select all columns including the new ones, though your code still only needs the original columns. Also when renaming some of the columns in the future, `*` will suddenly return different results which cause problems further down the road, whereas explicitly stating the columns to select will give you a clear error message in the right place.